# Set App Settings for Visual Studio Test Task in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a .Net Framework 4.6.2 Unit.Tests project, which has `App.config` file, in which it has some passwords in `<appSettings>` element. I want to update them in Azure DevOps build pipeline.
I'm using Visual Studio Test task to run the unit test. I tried to update `appSettings` in **Execution options > Override test run parameters**, but it didn't work as expected. 
[image]

I know that Azure App Service deploy task can update `appSettings` in **Application and Configuration Settings > App setttings**. I want something similar in Visual Studio Test task.
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: I suggest you use the keyvault for this kinf of situation

Comment: Yes. But even if I save it to the key vault and retrieve it back to DevOps variable, I am not able to set it to appSettings.

Comment: Why do you want to change Unit Test Project in release pipeline? Why do you need Unit Test project in release peipeline?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej The background is that our source code needs to be scanned by security vulnerabilities tools, if any hard-coded passwords found in source code, there will be an security warning, right? I want to pass the security checking, I set all hard-coded passwords to dummy one, then my unit test in DevOps fails. Yes I may went to a wrong direction at the beginning, but the answer give a right way to go - use runsettings. Should every question need to be technical exactly correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Override Test Run Parameters" section only applies to `runsettings` or `testsettings` files. It does not apply to app.config files.

> Override parameters defined in the TestRunParameters section of runsettings file or Properties section of testsettings file. For example: -key1 value1 -key2 value2. Note: Properties specified in testsettings file can be accessed via the TestContext using Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 or higher

If you want to configure something in the app.config. Try using a "[replace tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)" task (there are multiple options).

Our tests usually leverage the `runsettings` files. The file syntax is quite similar to the app.config, and you access the values via `TestContext`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019

```
  <!-- Parameters used by tests at run time -->
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />
    <Parameter name="webAppUserName" value="Admin" />
    <Parameter name="webAppPassword" value="Password" />
  </TestRunParameters>
```

```
[TestMethod]
public void HomePageTest()
{
    string appURL = TestContext.Properties["webAppUrl"];
}
```

Comment: Great solution... but if using Resharer testrunner it does not support this. Also using xUnit... it does not support this either. So I find it a bit restricted in that sens. But thanks for tip on Replace tokens task, will look into that.